# AFNetworking: how to post a ordered JSON

Tags: ios, json, web-services, afnetworking

I know that JSON specification says that an object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. But i really need to send a ordered JSON to a webservice. The problem is:

On the webservice (that i do not know or have access to the code) there's a step to convert my JSON to SOAP (where all objects must be ordered).

This is what i tried:

```
NSString *json = @"{'perf':1,'begin':'2013-07-17T15:35:33.659-03:00','end':'2013-08-01T15:35:33.659-03:00'}";


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                            path:@"/myPath" parameters:nil];

//set headers
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/json"];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"any-value" forHTTPHeaderField: @"User-Agent"];

//create the body
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:postBody];

//Add your request object to an AFHTTPRequestOperation
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:
     ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,
       id responseObject) {
         NSString *response = [operation responseString];
         NSLog(@"response: [%@]",response);
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);
     }];

[operation start];
```

So, how i can do this?

Comment: Sorry, it does not compute.  By definition JSON "object" entries are unordered.  Any web site that demands that they be presented in a specific order is badly broken.  (Of course, array entries *are* ordered, but that shouldn't be a problem for anyone to arrange.)

Comment: PS:  If hard-coding the JSON string didn't do the job for you I suspect you're misinterpreting the problem and there's something else wrong.

Comment: PPS: What is the purpose of this: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/json"];`?

Comment: Hard-coding the JSON string worked. There's a problem on the webservice. He's trying to convert my JSON to SOAP

Comment: If the web service doesn't accept valid JSON I'd be suspicious of it's reliability and certainly wouldn't trust it with anything related to money or privacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create the JSON text yourself (or find a library that offers ordering, if one exists).

Consider using an array of keys and creating the text for each key/value pair, then writing this (with appropriate JSON formatting) into an `NSMutableString`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what order you JSON has to be in. Regardless, you shouldn't be relying on `AFNetworking` to do any sort of manipulation of your data. Instead, you should do it yourself.

Since JSON can be represented as a `NSDictionary` (or `NSArray`), you should create your data structure using these classes, use the built in sorting methods to order them however you would like (alphabetically, etc), and then convert them to a JSON representation. This is instead of what you're currently doing, which is creating the JSON as a `NSString`.